# Show that a sequence is mutually orthogonal.

Tags: sequences-and-series

I found this test which was given to math majors in a local University and one of the question(problem) says

> Show that $\bigg\{\sin\bigg(\dfrac{n \pi x}{L}\bigg) \bigg\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is mutually orthogonal on $-L \leq x \leq L$.

I could not understand what mutually orthogonal means for a sequence. Can anyone elaborate this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well - do you know what mutual orthogonality means for an inner product space? If you Google mutual orthogonality, you get a lot of results. Or are you confused about those results?

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose I am not familiar with inner product spaces. I thought the problem didn't require that much technicality, but I guess I was wrong.

Comment: You can think of inner product spaces like vector spaces with dot products. The vectors here are functions, and the "dot product" here is integration. Two vectors are orthogonal if their inner product (or their "dot product" if you like) between them is $0$

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose Thank you! This is actually helpful.

Comment: No problem at all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** It means you have to show: For $m \neq n \implies \displaystyle \int_{-L}^L \sin\left(\frac{m\pi x}{L}\right)\cdot \sin\left(\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)dx = 0$. Use: $2\sin A\sin B = \cos(A-B) - \cos(A+B)$ to rewrite the integrand.